# Defining a seemingly simple Foldable instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

What would the Foldable instance for this datatype look like?

```
data X t = X t [X t]
```

I tried this:

```
instance Foldable X where
    foldMap f (X x xs) = f x `mappend` foldMap f xs
```

But got this error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = X a
When generalising the type(s) for `foldMap'
In the instance declaration for `Foldable X'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xs` is a list of items and `foldMap` needs to be applied to the individual items, not the list itself. Doing this with `map` gives a list of results that can be combined with `mconcat`:

```
instance Foldable X where
  foldMap f (X x xs) = f x `mappend` mconcat (map (foldMap f) xs)
```